# How to Parse JSON response into ng-repeat correctly in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to be able to use `ng-repeat` in order to parse my response on the front end.  I am having trouble parsing responses that have multiple items versus a single item using `ng-repeat` list.

I am able to parse; but I have to create 2 different list with separate `ng-repeat` configuration on the front end and add some ugly logic to not display if length of array is greater than one.

My goal is to have only one `ng-repeat` element in my partial and it handles both responses or a better approach to handle this requirement.

Detailed Explanation and jsfiddle below.
I want to use this ng-repeat setup for both JSON responses.

```
    <ul ng:repeat="report in reportConfigured.Reports">
    <li ng:repeat="reportItem in report">{{reportItem.ReportName.$}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Below is the response I get from my webservice when there are multiple reports.

```
{
    "Reports": {
        "@xmlns": {
            "$": "http:\/\/ws.wso2.org\/dataservice"
        },
            "Report": [{
            "ReportID": {
                "$": "20"
            },
                "ReportName": {
                "@xmlns": {
                    "$": "null"
                },
                    "$": "Examination Results"
            },
                "VisibleToPartner": {
                "$": "false"
            },
                "ReportType": {
                "@xmlns": {
                    "$": "null"
                },
                    "$": "Examination Report"
            },
                "TemplateID": {
                "$": "9"
            }
        }, {
            "ReportID": {
                "$": "163"
            },
                "ReportName": {
                "@xmlns": {
                    "$": "null"
                },
                    "$": "Scheduled Candidates with Test Center"
            },
                "VisibleToPartner": {
                "$": "false"
            },
                "ReportType": {
                "@xmlns": {
                    "$": "null"
                },
                    "$": "Examination Report"
            },
                "TemplateID": {
                "$": "220"
            }
        }, {
            "ReportID": {
                "$": "212"
            },
                "ReportName": {
                "@xmlns": {
                    "$": "null"
                },
                    "$": "Survey Report by Test"
            },
                "VisibleToPartner": {
                "$": "false"
            },
                "ReportType": {
                "@xmlns": {
                    "$": "null"
                },
                    "$": "Examination Report"
            },
                "TemplateID": {
                "$": "269"
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

I get this response from my service when there is only one report

```
 {
    "Reports": {
        "@xmlns": {
            "$": "http:\/\/ws.wso2.org\/dataservice"
        },
        "Report": {
            "ReportID": {
                "$": "212"
            },
            "ReportName": {
                "@xmlns": {
                    "$": "null"
                },
                "$": "Survey Report by Test"
            },
            "VisibleToPartner": {
                "$": "true"
            },
            "ReportType": {
                "@xmlns": {
                    "$": "null"
                },
                "$": "Examination Report"
            },
            "TemplateID": {
                "$": "269"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to parse both responses with the same `ng-repeat`.  I have attached a jsfiddle for more details.

http://jsfiddle.net/cejohnson/mdec9/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would transform what you get from the server before setting it as the `ng-repeat` datasource:

```
$http({...})
.success(function(data){
    if ( angular.isArray(data.Reports.Report) ) {
        $scope.reports = data.Reports.Report;
    }
    else {
        $scope.reports = [data.Reports.Report];
    }
});
```

And then

```
<ul ng:repeat="report in reports">
    <li ng:repeat="reportItem in report">{{reportItem.ReportName.$}}</li>
</ul>
```