# angularJS $http fails to parse complex json response from server

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http, get

I'm trying to show some images whose urls I get as a json response from a server.
Using examples such as [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wuc6M7?p=preview) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917238/problems-parsing-a-json-response-using-angularjs) was useful, but I can't seem to get it to work. 
I think the reason might be that the above examples parse simple json objects, while the response I'm trying to is more complex. I have tried unsuccessfully to handle that with the ng-repeater and ng-src directives, and also using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820830/how-to-parse-json-response-into-ng-repeat-correctly-in-angularjs).

This not an http problem (status is 200) or a json source problem(I have checked the response with Jsonlint  and it's ok).

my script:

```
            $http.get(path)
                .then(function(res) {
                    console.log("$http succeeded");
                    $scope.thumbList = res.data;
            });
```

my html:

```
    <div>
        <ul ng-repeat="item in thumbList.response.resultset.items" >
            <li>
                 <img ng-src="{{item.images.0.thumb_uri}}">
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: Looks good, what does the http response json object look like?

Comment: {response:{resultset:{items:[{images:{0:{thumb_uri:"http..."}}}]}}}

Comment: change the 0 into some words. angular have a parser that parse your expression. they not simply use eval. "item.images.0.thumb_uri" is syntactically does not mean it is right to use integer as key.

Comment: [wayne](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1655012/wayne) problem is I am not the maker of the json, only trying to parse it.

Comment: try assigning 

 $scope.thumbList = res.data.response.resultset.items;

and please notify if it works

Comment: @RishulMatta have tried, using the third example I linked to. Did not work, so now I try to change the element name from 0 to something else, in my .then()